# Spring Boot port forwarding 80 to 8080

Tags: spring, .htaccess, spring-boot, thymeleaf, centos7

I recently created a spring boot app and launched it to my remote server.  I am running centos7 and I have modified iptables to send port 80 to 8080 but that seemed to do nothing. I also currently have this in a .htaccess file to make it work:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80$ [NC]
RewriteRule index.html$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/ [P,S=1]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

My problem with the current solution is that It works great for the base url blah.com but any subsequent link of of that page will have blah.com:8080/page.html.  Thus how do I better manage URL's that are displayed to the client so they dont have the port.

I think the real problem is hepsia is running and appears to have installed httpd on port 80 already.  Does anyonke know where i can add a veirtualhost to hepsia's implementation of httpd?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Boot app to listen on port 80.

In `application.properties`...

```
server.port=80
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will not work unless your application is running as root on many Linux distributions. The standard way to bypass this is to run your application behind a webserver (which runs on port 80), and forward those web server requests to your app.

If this is overkill for your purpose you can set up iptables routing / redirect.

First make sure your ports are open

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then the redirect as follows

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```